# Pthread and Signal Assignment in C

Tags: c, pthreads, signals

I have an assignment and i'm stuck and I have no idea where the problem is, but I have to use one thread to takes in two numbers from a file, prints the numbers on screen, then another thread adds them two numbers together and prints them on screen.
Here's what I have so far but I can't seem to get it to work properly any help would be greatly appreciated.
**I should point out, I have to do this without the use of mutex's and semaphores.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef struct
{
     int a;
     int b;
} pair_t;

FILE *f;

static void * reader(void *data){
    pair_t *d = (pair_t *)data;
    sigset_t catch;
    int flag;

    sigemptyset(&catch);

    sigaddset(&catch, SIGUSR1);

    while(!feof(f)){
        sigwait(&catch, &flag);
        fscanf(f,"%d", &d->a);
        fscanf(f,"%d", &d->b);
        printf("Thread 1 submitting : %d %d", d->a, d->b);
        sleep(5);
    }
    return 0;
}

static void * calculator(void *data){
    pair_t *pa = (pair_t *)data;
    sigset_t catch;
    sigemptyset(&catch);
    sigaddset(&catch, SIGUSR1);
    int flag;

    while(1){
        sigwait(&catch, &flag);
        printf("Thread 2 calculated = %d\n",(pa->a + pa->b));
        sleep(5);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(f ==NULL){
        perror; 
    }
    if(f !=NULL){
        pair_t * p;

        sigset_t set;
        sigemptyset(&set);
        sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);

        pthread_t t1;
        pthread_t t2;

        pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, reader, (void *)&p);
        pthread_create(&t2, NULL, calculator, (void *)&p);

        pthread_join(t1, NULL);
        printf("Goodbye from Thread One");
        pthread_join(t2, NULL);
        printf("Goodbye from Thread Two");

        pthread_exit(NULL); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to figure out which thread will be scheduled first in your code. Please note that threads are not scheduled and started in order if invoking pthread_create function. So it is very possible that t2 will be scheduled before t1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your idea correctly you want reader() to read values and then submit them to calculator. If so then first of all you have to use pthread_kill() to send signal from reader to calculator. For that you need to make t2 visible to reader.
If you don't need back signal from calculator about finishing calculations then you can just remove sigwait() from reader. otherwise you have to send signal to t1 from calculator to let reader know that calculation is over and reader can continue reading values from file.

So, its a common case of producer and consumer.

Here the code below with some comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

typedef struct
{
     int a;
     int b;
} pair_t;

FILE *f;

pthread_t t1; // must be global for pthread_kill()
pthread_t t2; // must be global for pthread_kill()

static void * reader(void *data){

    pair_t *d = (pair_t *)data;
    sigset_t catch;
    int flag;

    sigemptyset(&catch);        
    sigaddset(&catch, SIGUSR1); 

    while(!feof(f)){
        fscanf(f,"%d", &d->a);
        fscanf(f,"%d", &d->b);
        printf("Thread 1 submitting : %d %d", d->a, d->b);
        pthread_kill(t2, SIGUSR1); // tell calculator() to start computations
        sleep(5);               // this is not necessary if confirmation signal from
                                // calculator() is used
        //sigwait(&catch, &flag); // if you need confirmation from calculator()
                                // then this can be enabled
    }
    return 0;
}

static void * calculator(void *data){


    pair_t *pa = (pair_t *)data;
    sigset_t catch;
    sigemptyset(&catch);
    sigaddset(&catch, SIGUSR1);
    int flag;

    while(1){
        sigwait(&catch, &flag);
        printf("Thread 2 calculated = %d\n",(pa->a + pa->b));
        sleep(5); // don't need if confirmation below is used
        //pthread_kill(t1, SIGUSR1); // enable this if confirmation 
                                     // from calculator is necessary
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){ 
    f = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    if(f ==NULL){
        perror;
        exit(1); // better to return here, because without file nothing to process
    }
    // no need to check, f != NULL already
    //if(f !=NULL){                     
        pair_t * p;

        sigset_t set;
        sigemptyset(&set);
        sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);

        //pthread_t t1;
        //pthread_t t2;

        pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, reader, (void *)&p);
        pthread_create(&t2, NULL, calculator, (void *)&p);


        pthread_join(t1, NULL);
        printf("Goodbye from Thread One");
        pthread_join(t2, NULL);
        printf("Goodbye from Thread Two");

        pthread_exit(NULL); 

    //}
    return 0;
}
```

Also, if you are using a couple of threads which both don't block some signal, then sending this signal to a process causes unpredictable behavior - any of them can catch signal and wake up and the remaining still be waiting for signal.